# plotting quantiles with geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to get as much information about my distribution as possible. I have created a boxplot using this code:

```
  ggplot(nkv.murgang, aes(x = factor(0), nkv.murgang$NK)) +
    geom_boxplot(notch = F, outlier.color = "darkgrey", outlier.shape = 1,
                 color = "black", fill = "darkorange", varwidth = T) + 
    ggtitle("NKV Murgang - Einfamilienhaus") + 
    labs(x = "Murgang", y = "Nutzen / Konsten \n Verhälhniss")
```

This yields:

[image]

Now i wopuld like to plot the corresponding values in the graph. Something like this ( in horizontal position):

[image]

Here is (part of) my data:

I have been trying different things, but I struggle due to the fact that I only know my x axis. Any tipps  how to overcome this?

Comment: please share data

Comment: @mtoto thanks. I have added the data

Comment: if you use `coord_flip()` your picture doesnt equal the output of your code.

Comment: @mtoto originally i had that, then i removed it, sorry! (fixed already)... it doesn't really matter if the graph is horizontal or vertical, the point is to plot the quantiles

Comment: @mtoto Indeed it is a (unintentional) duplicate. I found an answer to my problem by the link you provided. Thanks ! (What happens with duplicates? should i delete the answer? - I am quite new in the community)

Answer (score 0):

This seem to do almost what you want:

```
df = data.frame(val = runif(10)) # create dummy data

ggplot(df) + geom_boxplot(aes(y=val,x=1)) + # create the boxplot at x=0
geom_text(data=data.frame(q=as.numeric(quantile(df$val))), aes(x=rep(1.5,5),y=q,label=format(q,digits=2))) +  # add quantile values at x=0.5
geom_text(aes(x=0.5,y=median(df$val),label=format(quantile(df$val)[4]-quantile(df$val)[2],digits=2))) + # add interquartile value at x=0.5,y=median
geom_linerange(aes(x=0.55,ymin=quantile(df$val)[2],ymax = quantile(df$val)[4])) + # add linerange for interquartile
theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) + #remove x axis
labs(x = "Murgang", y = "Nutzen / Konsten \n Verhälhniss") # add label
```